# How do I use 2 variables in a Python for loop in the recommended Pythonic way?

Tags: python, c

I have the following `for loop` in `C` that I want to mimic in Python:

```
for (index = 0; index < n; ++index)
{
    for (i = 0, j = index; j < n; ++i, ++j)
    {
         'do something'
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant/Pythonic way to do this, or do I have to declare a variable outside of the loop like so:

```
for index in range(m):
    i = 0
    for j in range(index, m):
        'do something'
        i += 1
```

Comment: It ***really*** depends on what you're doing in that loop.  For instance, the loop you describe could be outright replaced by a list comprehension instead.

Comment: Probably, but it depends what you're doing in your loop. You rarely want to iterate on a range if you mean to use the value as an index.

Comment: `index` is just going be used as the bounds of my loop and `i` and `j` are going to be the indices to a nested list that I want to populate.

Comment: What does the nested list that you want to populate look like?  Could you add this information to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say without knowing more about what is going in the second loop, but as it's written I would say:

```
for index in range(n):
    for i,j in enumerate(range(index,n)):
        'do something'
```

would be the way you'd do that.

Comment: That appears to be what I was looking for. I didn't realize you can call `enumerate()` on a range to populate `i` and `j`. Thank you.

Comment: You can call enumerate on any iterable.